# Issues changing color on ggplot using scale_fill_brewer

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

I have a dataframe that I want to plot, where one column is a category and the other is counts.

I used `scale_fill_brewer`, but it's not changing any colors. The color is also off -- the bars are all neon colored.

How can I fix this?

The dataframe:

```
> dput(broad_cat)
structure(list(numbs = c(629, 526, 246, 86), labs = structure(c(4L, 
2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Propaganda", "Public Service", "Public Welfare", 
"Social Welfare"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("numbs", "labs"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

plot code:

```
p <- ggplot(broad_cat, 
            aes(reorder(broad_cat$labs, -(broad_cat$numbs), sum), 
                broad_cat$numbs))
p +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = broad_cat$numbs) + 
  labs(x = "Categories", y = "Counts") +
  ggtitle("Title[![enter image description here][1]][1]") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Fixed:

I included `fill` in `aes()`, but the graph is still black and white.

```
aes(reorder(broad_cat$labs, -(broad_cat$numbs), sum), 
    broad_cat$numbs), fill = broad_cat$numbs)
```

Comment: you have `fill` outside of `aes`

Comment: I fixed the code to ```aes(reorder(broad_cat$labs,-(broad_cat$numbs),sum),broad_cat$numbs),fill=broad_cat$numbs)``` but it's not changing color, it's still b&w

Comment: I have edited your question in order to improve the code readability. would suggest following my suggestions

Comment: Never use `$` inside `aes`.

Answer (score 3):

Since `numbs` is numeric with no repeating values, I understand that you use it for `fill` just to get some nice colors. Otherwise, as the error suggests, it is not going to work as `numbs` is continuous and your fill scale is discrete. Perhaps the following is what you want:

```
p <- ggplot(broad_cat, aes(reorder(labs, -numbs, sum), numbs))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = as.factor(numbs)), show.legend = FALSE) + 
  labs(x = "Categories", y = "Counts") + 
  ggtitle("Title[![enter image description here][1]][1]") + 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 9),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 9),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10, hjust = 0.5)) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

[image]

Where the main things were to use `fill` inside `aes`, convert `numbs` to a factor as to use the discrete scale, and also I removed all `broad_cat$...` as those will lead to problems and variables should be referred to directly by name.

Comment: @song0089, no problem, I'm glad it helped. And indeed you shouldn't never use `$` inside `aes` and, typically (though not always), there is no need for that elsewhere in the `ggplot` call either.